# EF 6.3: It creates the same migration for changing from DataAnnotation to FluentAPI

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-annotations, entity-framework-migrations, ef-fluent-api

I have data annotation:

```
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(150)]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string GuidName { get; set; }
```

Now we need to move it to Fluent API (and don't ask me why).
My code:

```
        this.Property(c => c.GuidName).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(150);
        this.HasIndex(c => c.GuidName).IsUnique(true).IsClustered(false);
```

It generates the following migration:

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        DropIndex("dbo.Companies", new[] { "CompanyUniqueString" });
        CreateIndex("dbo.Companies", "CompanyUniqueString", unique: true);
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropIndex("dbo.Companies", new[] { "CompanyUniqueString" });
        CreateIndex("dbo.Companies", "CompanyUniqueString", unique: true);
    }
```

as we can see, it does the same and has the same code in Up and Down. But why is it generated at all?

Comment: What migration was generated before these changes?

Comment: `CreateIndex("dbo.Companies", "CompanyUniqueString", unique: true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have removed `Index` data annotation from the field, that's why do you have `DropIndex(...)` line generated in the `Up()` method and corresponding `CreateIndex(...)` line in the `Down()` method. At the same time, you have added index via Fluent API, it gives you the rest (`CreateIndex(...)`  in the `Up()` method and `DropIndex(...)` in the `Down()`).

So, EF detects two changes in the model and doesn't check if Fluent API produces exactly the same index as removed data annotation.